# Property of normal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita conection. I need to prove the following.

Let $B$ be an open ball of radius $r$ in $T_pM$ such that $\left.exp_p\right|_B$ be a diffeomorphism over an open $U\subset M$ and
let $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$.

Let $F:T_pM\supset B\rightarrow U\subset M$ given by $F(x_1,...,x_n)=exp_p(x_1u_1+\cdots+x_nu_n)$. Clearly, $(U,F^{-1})$ is a chart. Show that

$$\left(\nabla_{X_j}X_i\right)_p=0$$

where $X_i:=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$.

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of your coordinates, $X_i$ is tangent to a geodesic through $p$ so $\left(\nabla_{X_i}X_i\right)_{p}=0$. For the crossed terms we use the *polarization* trick

$0=\left(\nabla_{X_i+X_j}X_i+X_j\right)_{p}=\left(\nabla_{X_i}X_{i}\right)_{p}+2\left(\nabla_{X_i}X_j\right)_{p}+\left(\nabla_{X_j}X_j\right)_{p}$.

As a side, these are called [geodesic normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Geodesic_normal_coordinates) and they are really useful to carry out computations in Riemannian geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how the map $F$ was necessary. Anyway, to prove that $(\nabla_{X_j}X_i) = 0$, you can use the identity $$2\langle\nabla_{X}Y, Z\rangle = X\langle Y, Z\rangle + Y\langle Z, X\rangle - Z\langle X, Y\rangle + \langle[X, Y], Z\rangle + \langle[Z, X], Y\rangle - \langle[Y, Z], X\rangle
$$
Now what is $[X_i, X_j]$ in this case?

Edit: a suggestion: you should take a look at Gauss's Lemma while you are at it :)

Comment: I add the part that explain waht if $F$ for, could you explain some more, i don´t get how to continue...

Comment: If you want to prove that the vector $\nabla_{X_i}X_j$ is $0$, you can try showing that the component of this vector in every direction is zero. In other words, you could try showing that the function $\langle\nabla_{X_i}X_j, X_k\rangle = 0$. For that, you can use the above formula

Comment: i think i get it, but i am a little confuse about the Gauss´s Lemma, i dont see the coneection